# Can k fold cross validation and randomizedsearchcv be used together?

Tags: python

```
Should I write k-fold cross validation with randomforestclassifier(n_estimators) model and then use randomizedsearchcv to find n_estimators value?
```

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=40)
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=cv, scoring='accuracy')
print('Accuracy: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores), std(scores)))
```

Accuracy: 0.978 (0.012)

```
mean_range = list(range(1, 100))
mean_scores = []
for k in mean_range:
    model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=k)
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
    mean_scores.append(scores.mean())
print(mean_scores)
```

With n_estimators=40, the accuracy was 97.8%. What method should I use to find a suitable n_estimators value in this case?

```
I drew a graph after looping from k=1 to 100, but there seems to be a better way.
```

```
I'm totally new to the code, so I'd appreciate it if you could give me an answer.
```